# How to find flower and animal icons for flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I need flower and animal icons for an application. When I looked at Pub.dev, I couldn't find a package containing flower and animal icons. Can you give an idea about what I can do?

I looked at these packages but there are no flower and animal icons.

**font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0**

**unicons: ^2.0.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material icons have some flower icons, but if you need something really specific you should use a `SvgPicture`, and download any SVG file.

Here is an example

```
SvgPicture.asset(
   "assets/img/your-icon.svg",
   height: 32,
    width: 32,
    color: Colors.black54,
),
```

To use this way you have to declare the assets folder in the `pubspec.yaml` and run a `flutter pub get` after that, an example`enter code here`:

```
flutter: 
  assets: 
    - assets/img/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I really wanted to know was if there is a ready made pack where I can use flower and animal icons.

Comment: Like I said Material has some flower Icons. But you probably won't find a package containing the Icons you're looking for, the easiest and fastest way is using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Flutter_Icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons).

Add this in your Flutter page:

```
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

   IconButton( 
      icon: const Icon(FontAwesome5.cat), //Example
      onPressed: () {},
   )
```

And remember to add the package to your dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
 dependencies:
 flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
```

Comment: This package is very good. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone stuggling to use this package see the package [`flutter_icons_null_safety`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons_null_safety)